# macbook retina NIC spiking CPU

Tags: macos

Frequently I'll be listening to music my Macbook Pro and it will skip and crackle every few seconds. `top -o cpu` shows kernel_task spikes to near 100% CPU, and it coincides with output of dmesg, for example:

```
AppleBCM5701Ethernet [100016add, ethernet]:        0 ffffffff flash_wait_for_cmd_done: Hw offline during read of nvram
AppleBCM5701Ethernet [100016add, ethernet]:        0        0 flash_read_word - Flash read timeout error

AppleBCM5701Ethernet [100016add, ethernet]: ff764928 9771908c code[i] crc wrong
AppleBCM5701Ethernet [100016add, ethernet]:        0        0 checkMacAddress - invalid (default or zero) MAC address
AppleBCM5701Ethernet [100016add, ethernet]:     ffff     ffff getAdapterInfo - Vendor is unknown
AppleBCM5701Ethernet [100016add, ethernet]:        0        0 start - getAdapterInfo failed, giving up
```

What's going on? How do I get these CPU spikes to stop?

Comment: There is a Stack [community](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) for Apple hardware/software related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Those messages suggest a firmware- or hardware-level failure of the Broadcom 5701 Ethernet NIC in your MacBook Pro. Possibly the little bit of flash memory that stores the Ethernet chip's firmware got corrupted, and the driver for that interface is unable to deal with it.

Sounds like time for a trip to the Genius Bar.